# How to determine Perl MIME::Base64 decode fail or not?

Tags: perl, base64

I have to decode some base64 string using Perl, and I want to know the docode is success or not.

How can I know the decode is OK? What will happen if my decode is failed?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "decode is failed" with `MIME::Base64::decode_base64`. It will simply ignore anything which does not fit, i.e. characters which are not valid base64 characters, incomplete padding at the end or any data following the end marker '='. Thus, it will always return something and in the worst case this will be an empty string.

Note that this behavior is not even wrong. At least some of the various Base64 standards explicitly require invalid characters to be skipped and none defines error handling in case of incomplete padding or data after '='. Still, the output of MIME::Base64 might be different compared to other implementations in case of invalid data.

Answer (score 2):

When using MIME::Base64's `decode_base64`, the decode is always deemed to be successful. Disallowed characters are ignored.

You could strictly verify that you have a valid base64 using the following:

```
my $c1 = '[A-Za-z0-9+/]';
my $c2 = '[AQgw]';
my $c3 = '[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]';
die "Invalid data\n"
   if $s !~ m{^(?:$c1{4})*+(?>$c1(?>$c2==|$c1$c3=)|)\z};
```

Whitespace is often used in the middle, so you might want to allow whitespace. (In fact, `encode_base64` includes whitespace in its output by default!)

The `=` are often left out, so you might want to allow missing `=`.

If you're worried about data corruption, include a hash of the data with the data.